# Why are screenreaders not speaking this dialog correctly?

Tags: jquery-ui, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

We have a modal dialog being popped up using jquery, just to alert a user of some info before they start using the main part of the application. Nothing complex, but for some reason all the browser/screenreader combinations I've tested with fail to read all or part of the dialog.

I've tested with IE8/JAWS15, Firefox/JAWS15 and Chrome/Chromevox.

Here is the HTML for the dialog itself.

```
<div id="divBrowserMessagePopup" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" aria-labelledby="divBrowserMessageTitle" aria-describedby="divBrowserMessage" hidden style="width: auto; min-height: 150px; height: auto; padding: 0px; border: 0px none;">
    <div id="divBrowserMessageUserPopup">
        <div class="modelpopup" style="border:0">
            <div class="modelpopup-top">
                <span class="sprite close" id="browserMessage-popupclose"></span>
                <div id="divBrowserMessageTitle"> <h1>Title of Dialog</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modelpopup-content">
                <div id="divBrowserMessage">this is a very important message we want the user to "see!"</div>
            </div>   
            <div class="model-button">
                <button class="button-lrg-pri float-right" id="btnBrowserMessageOk">OK</button>
            </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jqueryUI script we're using to make it a dialog and show it.

```
$('#divBrowserMessagePopup').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: '450px',
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css({ 'padding': '0', 'border': 0 });
        }

    });

$("#showDialog").click(function (e) {
        $('#divBrowserMessagePopup').dialog('open');

        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;       
    });
```

When the button is clicked, the dialog pops up just fine and the screenreader will usually speak "dialog" and possibly the title, but never the actual text of the dialog.

You might note that there are two divs with id "divBrowserMessagePopup," which I thought might be causing the problem. I removed it, and the dialog actually did work... but ONLY in Firefox for some reason.

Any idea why the text of the dialog would always be getting skipped?

Comment: Are you setting the focus into the dialog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Set tabindex="-1" on the "divBrowserMessagePopup" dialog
2. Change `$('#divBrowserMessagePopup').dialog('open');` to `$('#divBrowserMessagePopup').dialog('open').focus();` - note that you might have to do the focus inside a timeout because of animation delays
3. Set role="dialog" on "divBrowserMessagePopup"
4. Set role="document" on "divBrowserMessageUserPopup"
5. Remove aria-labelledby and aria-describedby from "divBrowserMessagePopup"

The rationale is the following:

First screen readers only read what is focussed (or at the SR buffer read position) so if you do not set focus, the SR will not know what to read. the first two steps above are to do that.

Second screen reader users can use the DOM navigation to discover new content, and the SR will automatically start reading the content of whatever gets focus, so you do not need the extra labelling for the dialog div but you should tell the SR what the role of the different components is. The last 3 steps will do that for you.

Finally, you will want to trap the focus in the dialog so that the screen reader cannot get out unless they click "OK". The steps to do this are not included here because they are off topic.

Comment: Doing 1, 2 & 5 worked. 3 and 4 broke IE8 and Firefox though... but everything works without those two so I'm good. :) (Oh, note that the jquery dialog function adds a div with the dialog role, so that's probably why setting it manually didn't work out well.)

Comment: Not joking: forget IE8! Which version of Firefox were you testing and was it broken with NVDA and Firefox combo?

Comment: I wish I could forget IE8, I have to use WinXP at work... :( I didn't try anything with NVDA, just JAWS and ChromeVox.

Comment: Firefox is best supported with NVDA - especially on older OSes

Comment: Good to know, that might explain a few other things. Unfortunately I can't download software here either... hopefully I can remember when I get home.

Comment: As CodeRedick mentioned, Doing 1,2 and 5 worked for me. 3 and 4 broke Internet Explorer , Firefox and edge browsers. So, i just added 1,2,5 changes and it works fine in all the browsers. thanks again !!! :)